# Facebook like button integration

Tags: facebook, wordpress, facebook-like

I am a wordpress developer and I am new to facebook api. I am creating an wordpress plugin using which users can just enter their facebook page url and insert the like button into the wordpress page.

What I would like to know is that can I use my facebook app id for including the javascript xdk for all users.

or

Is there any restriction or api limitation in doing so

Comment: I would say it's better if you request each user to create their own app. Speaking from security point of view, if one domain triggered some malicious activities on facebook systems this might affect the whole app and hence other domains/users.

Comment: Thankyou very much for your reply what I would like to know is what is the worst case of that situation will it affect my fb account from creating any other apps or just the fb will block that app alone.

Comment: Not sure about the specifics